# How to deploy a project that's split between Angular, Spring Boot and MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring, web

So I have a project - a e-commerce website.

The front-end is Angular - front-end interface to "add to basket" and "checkout".

The back-end is Spring Boot - via hibernate, accessing the database.

The database is MySQL - where the items you can buy are stored.

Spring Boot accesses the data (the items you can buy) via Hibernate, and using the @CrossOrigin annotation, the data is transferred and manipulated (add to basket, checkout, etc.) to the front-end. It's functional when the servers start up, but I don't know how to package all of that together so it works as an app, of sorts.

How can I deploy the project and have it be fully functional?

I've heard that Firebase, Heroku, AWS are candidates, but how does it all work?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your angular project inside spring boot project under `src/webapp` ,you can follow the jhipster guide https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app , it's a good example of integration spring boot with angular